# pdftoppm set starting index of converted png files

Tags: pdf

I'm currently using pdftoppm to convert a pdf to png files. I have a two page pdf, and I'm using the command:

```
pdftoppm -png filename.pdf filename
```

This generates two png files "filename-1.png" and "filename-2.png". Is there a way I can override what the index starts at? I want to zero-index the file names so it would create two files  that are named "filename-0.png" and "filename-1.png". Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is renaming the files afterwards not feasible?

Comment: I guess it could be done afterwards, I was just wondering if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Only the **PPM-root** can be specified; I don't see any way to modify the index used. The first page (which you can specify with the `-f` parameter) is **1**.

However the [source](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) is available, so feel free to modify it and change the base index to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change other than the base name. All files will be appended with `-{page_index}.{format}`

I would suggest writing the files to a unique directory, list the files in that directory and rename them according to your preference:

```
/converted/{uuid}/pdf-1.png -> /converted/pdf-0.png
/converted/{uuid}/pdf-2.png -> /converted/pdf-1.png
/converted/{uuid}/pdf-3.png -> /converted/pdf-2.png
```